# Pandas .str.replace and case insensitivity

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

Making the replace case insensitive does not seem to have an effect in the following example (I want to replace *jr.* or *Jr.* with *jr*):

```
In [0]: pd.Series('Jr. eng').str.replace('jr.', 'jr', regex=False, case=False)
Out[0]: 0    Jr. eng
```

Why? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `case` argument is actually a convenience as an alternative to specifying `flags=re.IGNORECASE`. It has no bearing on replacement if the replacement is not regex-based.

So, when `regex=True`, these are your possible choices:

```
pd.Series('Jr. eng').str.replace(r'jr\.', 'jr', regex=True, case=False)
# pd.Series('Jr. eng').str.replace(r'jr\.', 'jr', case=False)

0    jr eng
dtype: object
```

Or,

```
pd.Series('Jr. eng').str.replace(r'jr\.', 'jr', regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# pd.Series('Jr. eng').str.replace(r'jr\.', 'jr', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

0    jr eng
dtype: object
```

You can also get cheeky and bypass both keyword arguments by incorporating the case insensitivity flag as part of the pattern as `?i`. See

```
pd.Series('Jr. eng').str.replace(r'(?i)jr\.', 'jr')
0    jr eng
dtype: object
```

> **Note**
>   You will need to escape the period `\.` in regex mode, because
>   the unescaped dot is a meta-character with a different meaning (match
>   any character). If you want to dynamically escape meta-chars in patterns, you can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

For more information on flags and anchors, see [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) and [`re` HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto).

---

From the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/strings.py#L635-L669), it is clear that the "case" argument is ignored if `regex=False`. See

> ```
> # Check whether repl is valid (GH 13438, GH 15055)
> if not (is_string_like(repl) or callable(repl)):
>     raise TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")
>
> is_compiled_re = is_re(pat)
> if regex:
>     if is_compiled_re:
>         if (case is not None) or (flags != 0):
>             raise ValueError("case and flags cannot be set"
>                              " when pat is a compiled regex")
>     else:
>         # not a compiled regex
>         # set default case
>         if case is None:
>             case = True
>
>         # add case flag, if provided
>         if case is False:
>             flags |= re.IGNORECASE
>     if is_compiled_re or len(pat) > 1 or flags or callable(repl):
>         n = n if n >= 0 else 0
>         compiled = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
>         f = lambda x: compiled.sub(repl=repl, string=x, count=n)
>     else:
>         f = lambda x: x.replace(pat, repl, n)
> ```

You can see the `case` argument is only checked inside the `if` statement.

IOW, the only way is to ensure `regex=True` so that replacement is regex-based.

Comment: You should probably escape the `.` if you're going to turn on regex mode.

Comment: Thanks! The need for escaping the . was the actual reasoon why I disabled regexps (I was just being lazy).

Comment: @Toby If you don't want to have to escape it yourself, you can use `re.escape(mypattern)` to escape all regex metacharacters. Laziness FTW!