# Why isn't my str.replace() replacing this string?

Tags: python, pandas

I am simply trying to remove the string `'co '` (with space after 'co') from a pandas series:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'string':['co hello', 'co hello','co hello', 'co hello', 'co hello']})

print(x)

     string
0  co hello
1  co hello
2  co hello
3  co hello
4  co hello
```

Applying `str.replace()` and recording result to new column `string_clean`:

```
x['string_clean']=(x['string'].str.replace('Co ', '', case=False,regex=False))
print(x)

     string string_clean
0  co hello     co hello
1  co hello     co hello
2  co hello     co hello
3  co hello     co hello
4  co hello     co hello
```

The `co` is not removed.

Comment: Because it's case sensitive? 'co' instead of 'Co'?

Comment: set `regex=True`

Comment: The `case` argument has no effect on non-regex replacement. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863941/6260144) for more info.

Comment: @Erfan yes that works. But it's not a regular expression it's just a string. So when am I supposed to use `regex=False` or should it always be `True` even for literal strings?

Comment: If you don't have any differences in cases, just simply use: `x['string'].str.replace('co', '')`. If you have differences in cases, it's more elegant to write: `x['string'].str.replace('(?i)co', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit `regex=False`, because in [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) is default `regex=True` for substring replacement:

```
x['string_clean']= x['string'].str.replace('Co ', '', case=False)
print (x)
     string string_clean
0  co hello        hello
1  co hello        hello
2  co hello        hello
3  co hello        hello
4  co hello        hello
```

Comment: Ok, that works, But it's not a regular expression it's just a literal string according to the docs. That's why I set `regex=False`. When should I use `regex=False`?

Comment: @SCool - yes, it is not regex expression. But for substrings replamement is necessary `regex=True`.